# Is the date in the next 14 days or later

Tags: date, formatting, spreadsheet

I have created a spreadsheet in Google Drive for my travel planning. In this table I would like to use conditional formatting. The field contains the date until which a free cancellation of the hotel is possible. I would like to change the font and the text color.

- Case 1: I have more than 14 days until the date
- Case 2: I have 14 days or less left
- Case 3: it is the day or it is in the past.

I have tried, but my attempts have not resulted in any change to the font color.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

if A column holds your dates use custom formula in conditional formatting:

green:

```
=A1>TODAY()+14
```

yellow:

```
=(A1<TODAY()+14)*(A1>TODAY())
```

red:

```
=((A1=TODAY())+(A1<TODAY()))*(A1<>"")
```